# Doubt in dummit foote - direct subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-product, free-abelian-group

In Section $5.2$ of dummit and Foote,  the fundamental theorem of finitely generated ableian group is stated as

A finitely generated abelian group $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{1}} \times .....\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_s}$ , where
$a)r \ge 0$ (b) $n_{i+1}|n_i.$ Now can someone please explain $(b)$ as to why the condition is nesecarry and why do we call $r$ as the rank of the abelian group .It would be nice if an example is given to explain the rank of the group.

Comment: (b) isn't necessary. But that condition ensures uniqueness of the $n_i$.

Answer (score 2):

b) is just a condition that holds.

To explain where this condition comes from consider the direct product $C_2\times C_{9}\times C_{21}$. You can represent it first as $C_2\times C_9\times C_3\times C_7$ and then as $C_3\times  C_{126}$ which satisfies b).

If you consider the Abelian group as a $ \Bbb Z$-module and take a tensor product with the ring of rational numbers to get a $\Bbb Q$-module then that module will be free of rank $r$. It is also called the **$\Bbb Q$-rank** of the Abelian group.

Comment: Could you give an easy example ? I haven't studied modules and tensor products yet ..

Comment: Something that I feel is that $Z^r$ is generated by (1,1.....,1) so the group $G$ is actually being generated by $r$ copies of $Z$ so the dimension of the group (which I assume is what rank tries to tell me)is r and the invariant factors are $n_1,...,n_k$ which essentially represents  the elements of finite orders.Is this a correct explanation?@JCAA

Comment: $2$ doesn't divide $3$ so how does the condition hold?

Comment: If you haven't studied modules it is hard to understand why $r$ is called a rank. In fact there are two ranks: $r$  and somewhat more natural $r+s$ - the minimal number of generators of the group.  D-F tend not to explain such things. That is why I do not like the book.

Comment: @smita: $2$ does not divide $3$ but $3$ divides $126$.

Comment: You could describe $r$ in terms of the number of independent elements (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$).  This makes it similar to the definition of rank from linear algebra (without explicitly tensoring).

Comment: Yes, $r$ is also called the torsion-free rank and $s$ is called the torsion rank.

Comment: I looked up the definition of torsion-free rank and it is defined as the cardinality of the maximal linearly independent subset of A and then there are many definitions that follows.Where should I get my concepts clear from?And can someone please explain where I went wrong while defining the infinite ordered elements as being generated by $(1,...,1)$ - isn't this what torsion free rank means?I am confused.

Comment: For finitely generated Abelian groups it is equivalent. The point is that if $a$ is torsion then the set $\{a\}$ is linearly dependent.